# SharePoint server is not installed on this computer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-server

I am new to SharePoint and I am using SharePoint 2013. I have installed the SharePoint server 2013 on one server and I want to create web parts from vs 2010. But my vs 2010 is present on different pc and I am getting the below error.

```
"A SharePoint server is not installed on this computer” in SharePoint 2013".
```

I have search on net and found some links. I have used the below link to create the web parts.

Link : http://sharepointcustomization.blogspot.in/2012/10/sharepoint-server-is-not-installed-on.html

So I have done the below chagnes to create a web parts.

I have Copy the whole registry keys to my local pc.
Copy the SharePoint dlls at C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI from sharepoint server to local machine.
Copy the necessary sharepoint dlls to GAC by using below command.

```
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC> gacutil.exe -i "c:\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll"
```

I have restared my pc and geting the same error as "A SharePoint server is not installed on this computer” in sharepoint 2013".

Can any one help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Please don't cross-post questions on SO. Thanks.

Comment: You can install the VS 2012 /2013 on the  server where SP 2013 is installed and  start development.Otherwise, you can download the client side OM sdk , start programming using CSOM only.

Answer (score 1):

You can create new project and compile without SharePoint installed but to run and test you need SharePoint to be installed in your development machine.
Please refer this link.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/d6e34fe3-651a-4d3e-a801-321798da799c

Comment: thanks for you answer. As you said "You can create new project and compile without SharePoint installed", but i am not able to create SharePoint project in vs 2010. Can you help me.

Comment: You need to export [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\14.0] from registry and install it in your local machine. No other changes you need to do. You can create new SharePoint project in your local machine. I tried here. It works.

Comment: I am using vs 2010 and SharePoint server 2013. I have done the same thing on my PC and getting the error "A SharePoint server is not installed on this computer”. Can you help me please?

Comment: oh.. Then for SharePoint 2013 you might export 15.0 from registry and installed in your system right?

Comment: Yes, I have export 15.0 from registry and installed in my system. But getting the same error. Please can you help me?

Comment: If that does not work you need to install Visual Studio 2012 for creating SharePoint 2013 projects.

Answer (score 0):

Actual thing is that Visual Studio 2010 by default did not support Sharepoint 2013. For that you have follow bellow URL

And also take a look at this link which states the Requirement for SP 2013

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30722